# Nested if conditions for Tkinter Combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to use this function below for applying a nested condition, which first checks if the file is a text file and then checks the word in that file. If both are yes then the file entry is added into the combobox. But this function is not delivering me anything. Help is needed.

```
def find():
i = 0
keyword = tb4.get("1.0", END).replace('\n', '')
if len(tb2.get("1.0", END)) > 2:
    tid = tb2.get("1.0", END).replace('\n', '').replace("Destination Folder :", '')
    arr = [x for x in os.listdir(tid) if x.endswith(".txt")]
    while i < len(arr):
        x = os.path.join(tid, arr)
        with open(x) as f:
            if 'keyword' in f.read():
                combo2['values'] = arr
                f.close()
            else:
                pass
else:
    messagebox.showinfo(title="PROCEDURAL ERROR", message="FOLDER is not set. \nSet Destination")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "checks the word in the file", do you mean you're expecting it to check if `keyword` is in the _contents_ of the file, or in the filename? Because the latter is what you're checking—you'll find a file named `keyword.txt` or `has my keyword in it.txt`, but you won't find a file named `stuff.txt` that has `keyword` somewhere in its contents.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? What are you typing into the text widget, and have you examined `keyword` to see if it's what you think it is? Have you verified that `tid` and `arr` are what you expect them to be? Finally, what does "not delivering" mean? Can you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: One of the first techniques for debugging code like this is to remove the list comprehension and replace it with a loop so that you can more easily view the intermediate variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're problem is that you're expecting `'keyword' in x` to check whether the contents of the textfile contain your `keyword`. But that's wrong, for two reasons.

First, you're checking for the literal string `'keyword'`, not the string in the variable `keyword`.

Second, you're checking for that string in the filename, `x`, not in the contents of that file.

So, what you need is to write a function that checks whether a string exists in a file:

```
def file_has_keyword(filename, keyword):
    with open(filename) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    return keyword in contents
```

… and then you can call that function in your list comprehension, making sure to pass the variable `keyword` rather than the literal string `'keyword'`:

```
arr = [x for x in os.listdir(tid) if x.endswith(".txt") and file_has_keyword(x, keyword)]
```

---

Your edited version fixes only one of these two errors, and adds a whole slew of new ones.

First, you're still looking for `'keyword'` instead of `keyword`:

```
if 'keyword' in f.read():
```

Next, if you want to loop over all of the values in `arr`, just do `for filename in arr:`; don't try to write a `while` loop setting `i = 0` and `while i < len(arr):` and using `arr[i]`. It's much more complicated, with many more places to get something wrong.

And you did get something:

```
x = os.path.join(tid, arr)
```

You're trying to join the string `tid` to the whole list of strings `arr`. That doesn't make any sense. You probably wanted to use `arr[i]` here. But, again, it would be simpler to just use a `for` loop.

But meanwhile, your logic doesn't make any sense here:

```
if 'keyword' in f.read():
    combo2['values'] = arr
```

Now, if *any* of your files includes the keyword, you're going to set `combo2['values']` to the whole list of files, both those that do and those that don't match. If none of them match, you'll just leave `combo2['values']` alone.

What you want to be doing is gathering the matching files into a new list as you go. Then, at the end, assign `combo2['values']` that new list.

Also, the whole point of using `with` is that it automatically closes the file, so don't call `f.close()` inside a `with open(…) as f:`.

Finally, you don't need an `else` on an `if` statement; adding one just to `pass` doesn't do anything except make your code longer, and a bit slower, and make a human reader wonder what you actually wanted to do there.

But, really, the simplest way to fix all of this is to scrap this new code and try again. Just expand the list comprehension out into a loop exactly. Take this:

```
arr = [x for x in os.listdir(tid) if (x.endswith(".txt") and file_has_keyword(x, keyword)]
```

… and turn each clause into a nested statement, with an `append` at the bottom, like this:

```
arr = []
for x in os.listdir(tid):
    if x.endswith(".txt") and file_has_keyword(x, keyword):
        arr.append(x)
combo2['values'] = arr
```

Now, if there's a problem it should be pretty easy to fix it. For example, it looks like you need an `os.path.join` on the filename, right? So:

```
arr = []
for x in os.listdir(tid):
    pathname = os.path.join(tid, x)
    if x.endswith(".txt") and file_has_keyword(pathname, keyword):
        arr.append(x)
combo2['values'] = arr
```

It would also probably help to rename the variables to something meaningful. I have no idea what `tid` is supposed to be, or `x`. `arr` is obviously some kind of array (actually a list), but of what? Which combo is `combo2`? Something like this would be easier to debug:

```
filenamess = []
for filename in os.listdir(destdir):
    pathname = os.path.join(destdir, filename)
    if filename.endswith(".txt") and file_has_keyword(pathname, keyword):
        filenames.append(filename)
files_combo['values'] = filenames
```

Comment: I have tried to combine the two in a function as above, can it be improved.

Comment: @AmbrishDhaka As above where? Does the code in my answer not do what you want, or not work for you in some other way?

Comment: I tried your code, but It has the same problem `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'notes20180612110407.txt'`
The full path problem which is stored in variable 'tid' how to pass that

Comment: if you see above, I tried to pass path as `x = os.path.join(tid, arr)` but it does not work .

Comment: @AmbrishDhaka I updated the answer to explain. But I can't keep debugging your code step by step, especially if you keep rewriting the whole thing with each step. You need to figure out what part you don't understand, and ask about that specifically, and then, once you've got an answer, go back and try to write your code yourself. If you have a new problem, ask a new question, don't keep editing your existing one.

Comment: Many thanks, it great learning `tid` is just a stringVar taking value from textbox, where it trims the preceding clause and the line break to isolate the path as string.

Comment: Many thanks, It worked, although I need to read many times your suggestions to fully understand your explanation, many thanks for the effort.

Comment: If you may wish I can send you the entire code just to tell, what exactly  I am doing. It's my effort to raise some work for digital humatities